# Example of useful downcast with static_cast which does not produce undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, downcast, static-cast

I am wondering about a short code example of an application of downcast via `static_cast`, under conditions where *there is no undefined behaviour*.
I have looked around and I found quite a few texts (posts, Q&A, etc.) referring to fragments of the standard, explaining, etc.
But I found no examples that illustrate that (and that surprises me).

**Could anyone provide one such example?**

Comment: When the logic of the program ensures that the `static_cast` as a downcast is correct. The classical example is the CRTP answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic example:

```
class Animal {};
class Dog : public Animal {};

void doSomething() {
  Animal *a = new Dog();
  Dog *d = static_cast<Dog*>(a);
}
```

A more contrived example:

```
class A { public: int a; };
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};

void doSomething() {
  D *d = new D();
  int bValue = static_cast<B*>(d)->a;
  int cValue = static_cast<C*>(d)->a;

  // This does not work because we have two a members in D!
  // int eitherValue = d->a;
}
```

There are also countless other cases where you know the actual type type of the instance due to some flags or invariants in your program. However, many sources recommend preferring `dynamic_cast` in all cases to avoid errors.

Comment: Example 1 is a good simple example.
Why is example 2 a downcasting? It looks to me like an upcasting.

Comment: I have taken advantage of this simple case (silly me I didn't see it!) to fix (quite contrived) code I received.

Answer (score 5):

A downcast via `static_cast` is part of the typical implementation of the Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP). The example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

> ```
> template <class T> 
> struct Base
> {
>     void interface()
>     {
>         // ...
>         static_cast<T*>(this)->implementation();
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     static void static_func()
>     {
>         // ...
>         T::static_sub_func();
>         // ...
>     }
> };
>
> struct Derived : Base<Derived>
> {
>     void implementation();
>     static void static_sub_func();
> };
> ```

`Base` "knows" that it can downcast `this` to `T*` via `static_cast` (rather than `dynamic_cast`) because the whole purpose of `Base` is to be inherited by `T`. For more details on CRTP I refer you to the wikipedia article.

Comment: Good example of application for a programming technique.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio actually it is difficult to find examples that don't smell. The other answer has a good example, but I would argue that it needs a review and then refactoring. Imho it is a good intuition that downcasts aren't nice and should be done via `dynamic_cast` if at all.

Comment: Both answers were good, and they helped me better understanding what good uses could `static_cast` have.
This helped me on my way (I'm still not there, and I may have further questions) to fixing a code I received that uses `static_cast` leading to UB. Unfortunately, that code is too entangled to put together a reasonable MCVE that represents it (at this point).